# Failed to generate a configuration file for xfce4-xkb-plugin from source

Tags: development

I'm trying to generate a configuration file for xfce4-xkb-plugin from source and I get this error:

```
alex@alex:~/Repos/xfce4-xkb-plugin$ sudo ./autogen.sh 
Preparing package directory /home/alex/Repos/xfce4-xkb-plugin...
Running glib-gettextize --force --copy...
Copying file mkinstalldirs
Copying file po/Makefile.in.in

Please add the files
  codeset.m4 gettext.m4 glibc21.m4 iconv.m4 isc-posix.m4 lcmessage.m4
  progtest.m4
from the /aclocal directory to your autoconf macro directory
or directly to your aclocal.m4 file.
You will also need config.guess and config.sub, which you can get from
ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/config/.

Running intltoolize --automake --copy --force
cp: cannot create regular file `m4/intltool.m4': No such file or directory
intltoolize: cannot copy '/usr/share/aclocal/intltool.m4' to 'm4/intltool.m4'
```

How can I get the following files from the official repos?

1. codeset.m4
2. gettext.m4
3. glibc21.m4
4. iconv.m4
5. isc-posix.m4
6. lcmessage.m4
7. progtest.m4
8. config.guess
9. config.sub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely ignore the "Please add..." message.  It is benign.

The important bit is the last message.  Confirm that /usr/share/aclocal/intltool.m4 exists and that the m4 local directory exists.

As an aside, it's unusual to run autogen.sh with sudo, though that shouldn't create a problem.  You will just have to also run make under sudo.

Comment: yes it's exists. but ./autogen.sh without sudo gave me some another errors for incorrect permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use apt to grab all the dependencies needed to build a package with the `build-dep` option:

`sudo apt-get build-dep xfce4-xkb-plugin` should do the trick.

Comment: it doesn't did the trick for me, the same errors after ./autogen.sh

Comment: nice idea for getting right the dependencies but is not a solution for the "Please add..." message